# Which one takes less Execution time and why?

Tags: c, compilation, preprocessor

```
1. 
int main() { int a; a = 0; }
//OR 
2. 
#define ZERO 0 int main() { int a; a = ZERO; }
```

I think that the second one takes less execution time because it is preprocesssed.

Comment: They are equal. basic `C`.

Comment: First of all, build both programs with optimization enabled. Then compare the generated code for both. If (and I really mean *if*) they differ, then measure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the second one is just a define which will replace in preprocessor. No difference here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is correct. chandan should do this experiment if he is really interested.

Comment: But i have seen in most of the people Go for second one in large code

Comment: Both get optimized to an empty main() function with no contents... Don't worry about optimization before you have learnt the basics of C and taken a basic algorithm class.

Answer (score 1):

The one liner - compilation time and execution time are different metrics altogether!!

Any program, written in mid to high level language, is not executed *as-is* by the system. For C, it is the compiler, which takes the source file as input and produces the binary (machine-executable code). In the process, it incorporates a lot of *optimization* to the code.

In this case, it's most likely, that the compiler will optimize out the statements altogether, as they are not *used* meaningfully. Both the snippets are likely to generate the *same* binary (unless you forcefully turn off the optimization). If at all, you have to check the generated binary and perform the time-measurement to check the final result.

Comment: it is preprocessor, it will not reach optimization step.

Comment: @WedaPashi I didn't check reputation that much before replying. :D

Comment: @WedaPashi well, let's not discuss about the rep, that has nothing to do with the content. Afshin - Preprocessing would be done, that is not cosidered in the execution time anyway. finally the optimization will kick in before producing the binary, which has direct relation to the execution time. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: @SouravGhosh but replacing preprocessors is not considered the optimization step of compiler isn't it? This term is normally used for improving compiler's intermediate language to final executable code. That's why I commented on your reply.

Comment: @Afshin Understood, but the question was asked from the execution time perspective. :)

Answer (score 1):

They are equal. The compiler's preprocessor just replaces `ZERO` before doing anything.

Assuming it is written like this:

```
#define ZERO 0 
int main() { int a; a = ZERO; }
```

The program will be transformed to

```
int main() { int a; a = 0; }
```

before it is compiled and it **will not** reach optimization step.

**Update:**
Just to clarify, sometimes you see codes like this:

```
#define ERROR_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILED -1

char *buf = malloc(10);
if (!buf)
    return ERROR_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILED;
```

This can help code readability a lot, especially when you reuse these definitions.

Comment: But i have seen in most of the people Go for second one in large code.

Comment: @chandan it is for making code more readable, and for using some meaningful terms for some values. It makes code more readable if used correctly.

Comment: @chandan answer this to yourself why you need preprocessor in first place? and also `int a = 0;` is what people will use mostly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing my doubt.